# How to devide value and rejoin in python?

Tags: python, join

I'm working with IP, so on the loop it should be increasing the `a` value to different devices to retrieve data. How do I change the `a` value and rejoin as the IP address?

```
ip = 192.168.10.a
a = 100 + n    // assume n=5
// So a = 105
```

I need replace the IP `a` to particular value, and rejoin it as `IP` address.

Expected output:

```
ip = 192.168.10.105
// `n` is not a constant; it will change time to time.
```

Comment: You want to split the string and join a list? Try [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ip = "192.168.10.{}"
a = 100
for i in range(10): # assuming you want 10 IP addresses:
    new_ip = ip.format(a)
    print("Hello new_ip: {}".format(new_ip))
    a += 5
    if a > 255:
        # do something about it
        pass
```

Comment: perfect. it's useful @Pablo

Comment: @Dilux If it answer your question, consider marking the question as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

A version with [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) and [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range):

```
>>> ip = "192.168.10."
>>> for i in range(100, 260, 5):
...     new_ip = f"{ip}{i}"
...     print(new_ip)
... 
192.168.10.100
192.168.10.105
192.168.10.110
192.168.10.115
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a list to store and manipulate the ip and only convert it to a string for output afterward:

```
n     = 5
ip    = "192.168.10.0".split(".")    # [192,168,10,0]
ip[3] = 100+n
print(".".join(map(str,ip)))         # '192.168.10.105'
```

If your ip string actually contains the letter `a`, you could replace it directly to form a new string:

```
ip = "192.168.10.a"
print(ip.replace("a",str(100+n)))    # '192.168.10.105'
```